# Google Style Guide (Section Forward Decleration)

Tags: c++, design-guidelines

**Preface**

The Google Style Guide includes a list of disadvantages of forward declaration

1. **Forward declarations can hide a dependency, allowing user code to skip necessary recompilation when headers change.**
2. A forward declaration may be broken by subsequent changes to the library. Forward declarations of functions and templates can prevent the header owners from making otherwise-compatible changes to their APIs, such as widening a parameter type, adding a template parameter with a default value, or migrating to a new namespace.
3. Forward declaring symbols from namespace std:: yields undefined behavior.
4. It can be difficult to determine whether a forward declaration or a full #include is needed. Replacing an #include with a forward declaration can silently change the meaning of code:

Code:

```
  // b.h:
  struct B {};
  struct D : B {};

  // good_user.cc:
  #include "b.h"
  void f(B*);
  void f(void*);
  void test(D* x) { f(x); }  // calls f(B*)
```

If the #include was replaced with forward decls for B and D, test() would call f(void*).

5. Forward declaring multiple symbols from a header can be more verbose than simply #includeing the header.
6. Structuring code to enable forward declarations (e.g. using pointer members instead of object members) can make the code slower and more complex.

**Question**

I am particulary interested in the first point, as I cannot come up with a single scenario, where a forward decleration would *skip necessary recompilation when headers change*. Can anybody tell me how this can happen? Or is this something intrinsic to the google code base?

As this is the first point on the list it also seems rather important.

Comment: It sounds to me like they're confusing forward declarations with providing your own declarations of functions and types.

Comment: @Barmar So does it to me.

Comment: Since including a header file is a mechanism for providing forward declarations, @Barmar is undoubtedly correct.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Some of the guidelines are talking about forward declarations of incomplete types, which can be used when you just need a pointer. The header generally provides the complete declaration.

Comment: Simply put, the only time forward declarations are really needed is to allow for circular dependencies, and these should usually be in the header files themselves. There's little excuse for forward declarations in calling code.

Comment: @Barmar: The forward declaration is not enough to do overload resolution in all cases.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I understand, that's what the example below point #4 shows.

Comment: What seems to be clear is that the way this list is organized is confusing.

Comment: The wording is appalling. User code doesn't skip compilations. Build tools skip compilations.

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot come up with a single scenario, where a forward declaration would *skip necessary recompilation when headers change.*

I think this is a bit unclear too, and perhaps could be worded a little more clearly.

**What could it mean for a dependency to be *hidden?***

Let’s say your file `main.cc` needs `header.h` in order to be built correctly.

- If `main.cc` includes `header.h`, then this is a *direct* dependency.
- If `main.cc` includes `lib.h`, and then `lib.h` includes `header.h`, then this is an *indirect* dependency.
- If `main.cc` somehow depends on `lib.h` but does not generate a build error if `lib.h` is not included, then I might call this a *hidden* dependency.

I don’t think the word *hidden* is a commonplace term for this, however, so I agree that the wording could be refined or expanded.

### How does this happen?

I have `main.c`, `lib.h`, and `types.h`.

Here is `main.c`:

```
#include "lib.h"
void test(D* x) { f(x); }
```

Here is `lib.h`:

```
#include "types.h"
void f(B*);
void f(void*);
```

Here is `types.h`:

```
struct B {};
struct D : B {};
```

Now, `main.cc` depends on `types.h` in order to generate the correct code. However, `main.cc` only has a direct dependency on `lib.h`, it has a *hidden* dependency on `types.h`. If I use forward declarations in `lib.h`, then this breaks `main.cc`. And yet `main.cc` still compiles!

And the reason that `main.cc` breaks is because it does not include `types.h`, even though `main.cc` depends on the declarations in `types.h`. Forward declarations make this possible.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Isn't there a requirement that the format of a pointer isn't dependent on the layout of the type it points to?

Comment: @Barmar: Without a forward declaration, you must recompile `main.cc` because `types.h` has changed.

Comment: True, but since it doesn't declare any `A` objects, there shouldn't be a problem if you don't recompile.

Comment: @Barmar: Your build system is not that smart. All it knows is that `types.h` has changed.

Comment: Right, so it recompiles `main.cc` even though it doesn't really need to. The guideline implies that recompiling is necessary.

Comment: Or do they mean "otherwise necessary"?

Comment: @Barmar: Recompiling is necessary, if you want to have verifiable builds.

Comment: @Barmar: Note that it in large code bases, it is universally considered a bad idea to let users choose which files to recompile.

Comment: Good point. But what "dependency" is being hidden, as stated in the guideline? If there's any real dependency that requires recompilation, the code should fail to compile at all without the header.

Comment: Unless it's like the example after #4.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I think reasoning regarding "why recompilation is necessary in this case" should also be a part of an answer. That's the part which is especialy unclear at least for me

Comment: @Barmar: There is a very real dependency… the code depends on `b.h` being included. The dependency is “hidden” because you don’t get an error message when `b.h` is not included, instead, you call the wrong overload.

Comment: Seems to me this is a problem with void* not with forward declarations. If there is no other example, this rule seems silly.

Comment: Context: [a question of Enigma22134's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996751/how-is-it-that-a-forward-declaration-can-hide-a-dependency-and-cause-user-code-t) has been closed as a dupe of this question.

Comment: @Enigma: A lot of rules for large, old codebases seem silly when you think about them from the perspective of greenfield projects.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes that is true. But I wouldn't consider the project I'm on greenfield. Even with build farms our current project still takes at least an 40-60minutes for a full compile; even with extensive usage of forward declarations. There are a few cases where we have wide shared headers and touching one of those causes at least a ~20 recompile. Without forward declarations it would seem that many more header's would turn into these kind of land minds. Perhaps not though.  

For clarity, I think your answer is great for this question. I just wonder if `void*` is the primary motivation.

Comment: @Enigma: Google addressed this problem with aggressive shared caches for build artifacts and a massive pool of workers, so even large builds are fairly fast.  The `void *` here is just the simplest way I could think to illustrate. The real issue being illustrated is that different overrides get called if a class is forward declared, and this also happens with implicit constructors or conversion operators, etc. The example with `void *` is just the simplest, shortest one I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

> I am particulary interested in the first point, as I cannot come up with a single scenario, where a forward decleration would skip necessary recompilation when headers change. Can anybody tell me how this can happen?

It will happen because dependency trackers cannot deduce that something in the header file that defines the class changed if you use a forward declaration of the class. However, there is nothing intrinsically wrong about that in most cases.

> Or is this something intrinsic to the google code base?

The posted code block about `D` makes sense. If you don't `#include` the header that defines `D` but provide a mere forward declaration, the call to `f(x)` will resolve to `f(void*)`, which is not what you want.

IMO, avoiding forward declarations in favor of `#include`ing the header files is a very expensive price to pay to account for just the above use case. However, if you have enough hardware/software resources that the cost of `#include`ing header files is not a factor, I can see how one could justify such a recommendation.

Comment: What's confusing is that this is provided as an example for point #4 instead of point #1.

Comment: @Barmar, indeed. My guess is that somebody got bit by #4 at some point and decided that pain/cost of a bug introduced by it is too much, and hence decided to avoid it altogether by paying the price of a bit of extra compilation time.